# multiple actions on button with if statement in xcode4

Tags: xcode4

First of all, I'm very new to the Xcode 4 and Obj C and I m trying to build a survey function with only one navigation button. I need a method for my navigation button which will produce the result that if users select the first option and then select the navigation button, it will bring them to the second view controller while if they select the second option the navigation button will take them to another view. Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat. I wish that other people would have posted to this. If it helps at all,   the if/else statement in the code snippet library probably holds the keys, now we just need to find the lock.

```
if (<#condition#>) {
  <#statements-if-true#>
} else {
  <#statements-if-false#>
}
```

I am still learning here, but I know that an important conceptual distinction is that you can handle this survey in one of at least two ways:

1. Use if/then logic to branch out to different questions.
2. Have the same questions for everyone, storing the answers in a plist file and then at the end, based on the results gather, branch at that point to final results screens.

This was posted last year so you may be well ahead of me, but as I find out more, I'll post here. I'll be happy to add to the reference resources.

– David